# cannot find mx:DateChooser in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6, datechooser

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9b.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63b33-7fd3

Shows that mx:DateChooser control can be used in Flash Builder 4.6

I cannot find it in the codehint.

Please advise on how do I have a DateChooser control for use in Flash Builder 4.6

Update:

I really cannot find datechooser as seen in this screenshot.
http://cl.ly/EJKp

definitely I am using sdk4.6 for flex also shown here.
http://cl.ly/EJT0

Comment: Can you confirm you are selecting the 4.6 sdk in your properties? Also code hinting can be flaky in flex builder. Have you tried example code  to see that it compiles regardless of code hinting.

Comment: You must be targeting mobile development with Flex 4.6 SDK, the usage of mx:DateChooser is absolutely discouraged at mobile devices, that's why it is not code-hinted.

Anyway, if this is your case, you can try to follow the following instructions at this blog to make look of mx|DateChooser component more "mobile friendly".

Comment: What blog are you talking about JabbyPanda?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your script header contains things as following:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
```

Comment: Please see the screenshots I have just placed inside the question itself

Answer (score 0):

If the Flash Builder project settings have the Flex Build Path configured with a component set of "Spark only" then MX components like <mx:DateChooser> will not be available.  One way to fix this is to change the component set to "MX + Spark".

However, a trade-off of this approach is that the project will be able to compile a web application but not a mobile application.  Another solution is to use a spark only DatePicker (actually, DateChooser and DateField).  For example, here is an  [open source DateChooser](https://github.com/pdpsolutions/px/blob/master/visual/DateChooser.mxml) component.